# Kruskal Wallis test gives significance, multiple comparision table doesn't

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, nonparametric, multiple-comparisons, kruskal-wallis-test

I'm comparing physico-chemical properties of 8 different kefir samples like viscosity at different storage times. I have 4 viscosity measurements for each group. When I conduct Kruskal Wallis test; according to the test statics p value is smaller than 0,05. So there is a difference at least between two groups.But when I conduct post hoc test(Tamhane or Dunnet) there's not a significant difference between any groups as I read from the multiple comparision table. And also when standard error is zero there's no value for significance, which is shown with ' - '. How can I investigate which groups have a significant difference as it's reported at Kruskal Wallis?

as an example:  kefir/Mean Difference/ Std. Error /Sig.

```
            AC1/-,6500/ ,0500/,754

            AC2/-,6000/ ,0000/ -
```

Comment: Giving the details of the specific example at hand might clarify your question.

Comment: I'm testing viscosities of 8 kefir samples.according to Kruskal Wallis test statics p value is smaller than 0,05 but at posthoc multiple comparision table there's no diffence between means and also when standard error is zero there's no value for significance for example kefir/mean diff./st.er./ sign(p) AC3/ 0,80/ 0,00/ -- B/ -1,30/ 0,20/0,943 BC2/ -1,60/0,0/--  BC3/0,80/0,0/--

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question with the information that is now in your comment. You may also want to say what you are trying to find out. Finally, I'm unclear about your use of "homogeneity" in your question.

Comment: Once the K-W test rejects @ 5% $H_0:$ 'not all equal' according to one criterion, you may perform _ad hoc_ tests to try to determine what the pattern of differences might be. To prevent possible false discovery from many tests at 5% level, the _ad hoc_ tests use a more stringent criterion for declaring differences among groups. Thus it sometimes happens that _ad hoc_ tests find no significant differences. This is especially likely if the K-W P-value is just barely below 5%. // Cautions about false discovery aside, one might feel it's fair to say two most extremely different groups must differ.

Comment: Is it possible to perform 'ad hoc' test in SPSS?